# Error after upgrade

Tags: debugging, doom, error, debug-on-error

I upgraded doom yesterday. Unfortunately, since then I get the following error whenever I `doom run` :

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ‘/Users/*****/.emacs.d/.local/etc/@/init.27.elc’:

Error caused by user's config or system: /Users/*****/.doom.d/config.el, (end-of-file /Users/*****/.doom.d/config.el)

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the ‘--debug-init’ option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

The error file I get when I `doom run --debug-init` does not help me at all, or, at least, I cannot read it correctly. Can someone help me figuring out what the problem is?

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (doom-user-error "/Users/*****/.doom.d/config.el" (end-of-file "/Users/*****/.doom.d/config.el"))
  signal(doom-user-error ("/Users/*****/.doom.d/config.el" (end-of-file "/Users/*****/.doom.d/config.el")))
  (condition-case e (load path noerror 'nomessage) ((debug doom-error) (signal (car e) (cdr e))) ((debug error) (setq path (locate-file path load-path (get-load-suffixes))) (signal (cond ((not (and path (featurep 'doom))) 'error) ((file-in-directory-p path (expand-file-name "cli" doom-core-dir)) 'doom-cli-error) ((file-in-directory-p path doom-core-dir) 'doom-core-error) ((file-in-directory-p path doom-user-dir) 'doom-user-error) ((file-in-directory-p path doom-profile-dir) 'doom-profile-error) ((file-in-directory-p path doom-modules-dir) 'doom-module-error) ('doom-error)) (list path e))))
    path = "/Users/*****/.doom.d/config.el"
    noerror = nil
    e = (end-of-file "/Users/*****/.doom.d/config.el")
  doom-load("~/.doom.d/config")
  byte-code("\305\306!\204\f\0\305\307!\2030\2\10\30\310\211\203 \0\211@\311\1!\210\1A\266\202\202\17\0\210\312\21\313\22\314\315\316\"\210\314\317\320\"\210\314\321\322..." [doom-context doom-modules doom-disabled-packages custom-file doom-module-context doom-context-p init reload (modules) doom-context-push #<hash-table equal 43/65 0x4b32c76f> nil setplist :core (nil [0 -110 -110 :core nil nil nil]) :user (nil [1 105 -105 :user nil nil nil]) :completion (company [3 0 0 :completion company nil nil] vertico [4 0 0 :completion vertico nil nil]) :ui (deft [5 0 0 :ui deft nil nil] doom [6 0 0 :ui doom nil nil] doom-dashboard [7 0 0 :ui doom-dashboard nil nil] hl-todo [8 0 0 :ui hl-todo nil nil] ophints [9 0 0 :ui ophints nil nil] popup [10 0 0 :ui popup (+defaults) nil] treemacs [11 0 0 :ui treemacs nil nil] vc-gutter [12 0 0 :ui vc-gutter nil nil] vi-tilde-fringe [13 0 0 :ui vi-tilde-fringe nil nil] workspaces [14 0 0 :ui workspaces nil nil]) :editor (evil [15 0 0 :editor evil (+everywhere) nil] file-templates [16 0 0 :editor file-templates nil nil] fold [17 0 0 :editor fold nil nil] snippets [18 0 0 :editor snippets nil nil]) :emacs (dired [19 0 0 :emacs dired nil nil] electric [20 0 0 :emacs electric nil nil] undo [21 0 0 :emacs undo (+tree) nil] vc [22 0 0 :emacs vc nil nil]) :term (eshell [23 0 0 :term eshell nil nil]) :checkers (syntax [24 0 0 :checkers syntax nil nil]) :tools (debugger [25 0 0 :tools debugger nil nil] eval [26 0 0 :tools eval (+overlay) nil] lookup [27 0 0 :tools lookup nil nil] lsp [28 0 0 :tools lsp nil nil] magit [29 0 0 :tools magit nil nil] pdf [30 0 0 :tools pdf nil nil] biblio [31 0 0 :tools biblio nil nil]) :os (macos [32 0 0 :os macos nil nil]) :lang (emacs-lisp [33 0 0 :lang emacs-lisp nil nil] json [34 0 0 :lang json nil nil] latex [35 0 0 :lang latex (+latexmk +cdlatex +lsp +fold) nil] markdown [36 0 0 :lang markdown nil nil] org [37 0 0 :lang org (+journal + roam2 + notes) nil] python [38 0 0 :lang python (+lsp +conda +cython) nil] rust [39 0 0 :lang rust nil nil] sh [40 0 0 :lang sh nil nil] yaml [41 0 0 :lang yaml nil nil]) :config (use-package [2 -111 -111 :config use-package nil nil] default [42 0 0 :config default (+bindings +smartparens) nil]) [2 -111 -111 :config use-package nil nil] doom-load "~/.emacs.d/modules/config/use-package/init" [0 -110 -110 :core nil nil nil] "~/.emacs.d/lisp/init" doom-run-hooks doom-before-modules-init-hook [15 0 0 :editor evil (+everywhere) nil] "~/.emacs.d/modules/editor/evil/init" doom-after-modules-init-hook doom-before-modules-config-hook [3 0 0 :completion company nil nil] "~/.emacs.d/modules/completion/company/config" ...] 4)
  load("/Users/*****/.emacs.d/.local/etc/@/init.27.elc" noerror nomessage nosuffix)
  (progn (load init-file-name 'noerror 'nomessage 'nosuffix))
  (if init-file-name (progn (load init-file-name 'noerror 'nomessage 'nosuffix)))
  (let ((init-file-name (file-name-concat doom-profile-dir (format "init.%d.elc" emacs-major-version)))) (setq user-init-file t) (if init-file-name (progn (load init-file-name 'noerror 'nomessage 'nosuffix))) (if (eq user-init-file t) (progn (signal 'doom-nosync-error (list init-file-name)))) (setq user-init-file (concat (string-remove-suffix ".elc" user-init-file) ".el")))
  (progn (let ((init-file-name (file-name-concat doom-profile-dir (format "init.%d.elc" emacs-major-version)))) (setq user-init-file t) (if init-file-name (progn (load init-file-name 'noerror 'nomessage 'nosuffix))) (if (eq user-init-file t) (progn (signal 'doom-nosync-error (list init-file-name)))) (setq user-init-file (concat (string-remove-suffix ".elc" user-init-file) ".el"))))
  (if init-file-user (progn (let ((init-file-name (file-name-concat doom-profile-dir (format "init.%d.elc" emacs-major-version)))) (setq user-init-file t) (if init-file-name (progn (load init-file-name 'noerror 'nomessage 'nosuffix))) (if (eq user-init-file t) (progn (signal 'doom-nosync-error (list init-file-name)))) (setq user-init-file (concat (string-remove-suffix ".elc" user-init-file) ".el")))))
  (condition-case error (if init-file-user (progn (let ((init-file-name (file-name-concat doom-profile-dir (format "init.%d.elc" emacs-major-version)))) (setq user-init-file t) (if init-file-name (progn (load init-file-name 'noerror 'nomessage 'nosuffix))) (if (eq user-init-file t) (progn (signal 'doom-nosync-error (list init-file-name)))) (setq user-init-file (concat (string-remove-suffix ".elc" user-init-file) ".el"))))) ((debug error) (display-warning 'initialization (format-message "An error occurred while loading `%s':\n\n%s%s%s\n\nTo ..." user-init-file (get (car error) 'error-message) (if (cdr error) ": " "") (mapconcat #'(lambda (s) (prin1-to-string s t)) (cdr error) ", ")) :warning) (setq init-file-had-error t)))
  (let ((debug-on-error debug-on-error-initial)) (condition-case error (if init-file-user (progn (let ((init-file-name (file-name-concat doom-profile-dir ...))) (setq user-init-file t) (if init-file-name (progn (load init-file-name ... ... ...))) (if (eq user-init-file t) (progn (signal ... ...))) (setq user-init-file (concat (string-remove-suffix ".elc" user-init-file) ".el"))))) ((debug error) (display-warning 'initialization (format-message "An error occurred while loading `%s':\n\n%s%s%s\n\nTo ..." user-init-file (get (car error) 'error-message) (if (cdr error) ": " "") (mapconcat #'(lambda ... ...) (cdr error) ", ")) :warning) (setq init-file-had-error t))) (or (eq debug-on-error debug-on-error-initial) (setq debug-on-error-should-be-set t debug-on-error-from-init-file debug-on-error)))
  (let ((debug-on-error-from-init-file nil) (debug-on-error-should-be-set nil) (debug-on-error-initial (if (eq init-file-debug t) 'startup init-file-debug)) (inhibit-null-byte-detection t)) (let ((debug-on-error debug-on-error-initial)) (condition-case error (if init-file-user (progn (let ((init-file-name ...)) (setq user-init-file t) (if init-file-name (progn ...)) (if (eq user-init-file t) (progn ...)) (setq user-init-file (concat ... ".el"))))) ((debug error) (display-warning 'initialization (format-message "An error occurred while loading `%s':\n\n%s%s%s\n\nTo ..." user-init-file (get (car error) 'error-message) (if (cdr error) ": " "") (mapconcat #'... (cdr error) ", ")) :warning) (setq init-file-had-error t))) (or (eq debug-on-error debug-on-error-initial) (setq debug-on-error-should-be-set t debug-on-error-from-init-file debug-on-error))) (if debug-on-error-should-be-set (progn (setq debug-on-error debug-on-error-from-init-file))))
  startup--load-user-init-file@init-doom(#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x4b2dd1e7>) #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x4b2dd1fd>) t)
  apply(startup--load-user-init-file@init-doom (#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x4b2dd1e7>) #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x4b2dd1fd>) t))
  startup--load-user-init-file(#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x4b2dd1e7>) #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x4b2dd1fd>) t)
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```